# Remove JQuery Dialog styles

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Being new to JQuery, I have done a lot of searching and tried all the solutions I found to remove the default dialog styles.  I want to override their styles and apply my own styles to have a consistent look.

```
function showOrderDetails(num,id) {

             $.post("OrderDetailMini.aspx", "OrderNum=" + num + "," + id, function (retData) {
                 $("#currentdetail").html(retData).dialog('option', 'title', "Order Number: " + num).dialog("open");
                 $("link[href*=jquery-ui.css]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
             });
         }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="currentdetail" > </div>
```

**ORDERDETAILMINI.ASPX:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Content/Site.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
      <asp:GridView ID="DetailsView2" runat="server"
            AutoGenerateColumns="false"
            AllowPaging="false"
            VerticleScrollBar="auto"
            AllowSorting="true"
            CssClass="gridview">
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridviewHeaderStyle" />
            <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="gridviewAlternatingRowStyle" />
      <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PART_NBR" HeaderText="PART #" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="MFG_PART" HeaderText="MFG Part #" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PART_DESC" HeaderText="DESCRIPTION" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="inv_boh" HeaderText="Avail Qty" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="QUANTITY" HeaderText="Ordered Qty" />
      </Columns>
      </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Couldn't you just go to where the CSS file is on your site and replace their code with yours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you inspect the element with your browser, you'll find the corresponding classes to edit.

Then, you can just edit them in the .css file they provide - ! It's that easy !

Alternatively, instead of editing their stylesheet, you can just add `!important` to the end of your own css rules.